# Why is std::string constructor resetting GetLastError

Tags: c++, winapi, error-handling

I'm calling Windows APIs from C++ code and I have a helper method to do the `FormatMessage` stuff and throw an exception for error handling. The signature of the function is

```
void throw_system_error(const std::string& msg_prefix, DWORD messageid)
```

I've noticed something strange. This code does not work properly:

```
handle = ...;
if (handle == NULL) {
    throw_system_error("something bad happened", GetLastError());
}
```

The error code that is passed to  `throw_system_error` is always zero.

Where as this works just fine:

```
handle = ...;
if (handle == NULL) {
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    throw_system_error("something bad happened", error);
}
```

Some more investigation showed that this version has the same problem:

```
handle = ...;
if (handle == NULL) {
    std::string msg("something bad happened");
    DWORD error = GetLastError();
    throw_system_error(msg, error);
}
```

It looks for all the world as if the constructor of `std::string` is resetting the error code.

My guess would be that `std::string` is allocating memory internally which causes some system call that then sets the last error back to zero.

Anyone knows what is actually going on here?

Visual C++ 2015, 64bit.

Comment: Your code is broken. Simple as that. Call `GetLastError` before you call any other API function. Obviously a call to allocate memory is liable to call `SetLastError`. I'm quite sure this has been asked here before.

Comment: The code is broken, but I was asking for the root cause, not a fix. To add to the mistery, I've tested HeapAlloc and it does not modify last-error. But malloc sets it to zero. Which is not documented on msdn as the documentation of GetLastError demands. So... which answer should I accept?

Comment: `malloc` is outside the remit of the MSDN Win32 documentation. It can do what it likes.

Comment: You might want to consider throwing a [std::system_error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error) constructed from just the error code. If you need to add a string prefix at an arbitrary subsystem boundary, you can implement code to do so in an appropriate `catch` clause in the interface implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see the [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation:

> Most functions that set the thread's last-error code set it when they
>   fail. However, some functions also set the last-error code when they
>   succeed.
>
> You should call the GetLastError function immediately when a
>   function's return value indicates that such a call will return useful
>   data. That is because **some functions call SetLastError with a zero
>   when they succeed**, wiping out the error code set by the most recently
>   failed function.

So there is one function calling SetLastError, very likely one that allocates memory:
When you construct a string, `new` is called to allocate memory.

Now, let's see `new`'s implementation in vc++. There is a very good answer to that question in Stack Overflow : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/293209

> It depends if you are in debug or release mode. In release mode, there is HeapAlloc/HeapFree which are kernel functions,
>
> while in debug mode (with visual studio) there is a hand written
>   version of free and malloc (to which new/delete are re-directed) with
>   thread locks and more exceptions detection, so that you can detect
>   more easily when you did some mistakes with you heap pointers when
>   running your code in debug mode.

So in release mode, the function called is [HeapAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/aa366597(v=vs.85).aspx), which does **NOT** call SetLastError. From the documentation:

> If the function fails, it **does not call** SetLastError

So the code should work properly in release mode.
However, in the debug implementation, the function FlsGetValue is called, and that function **calls SetLastError** when succeeded.

It's very easy to check this,

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
int main() {

    DWORD t = FlsAlloc(nullptr);
    SetLastError(23); //Set error to 23
    DWORD error1 = GetLastError(); //store error

    FlsGetValue(t); //If success, it is going to set error to 0

    DWORD error2 = GetLastError(); //store second error code

    std::cout << error1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << error2 << std::endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs the following:

```
23
0
```

So FlsGetValue has called SetLastError(). To prove that it is called only on debug we can do the following test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
int main() {

    DWORD t = FlsAlloc(nullptr);
    SetLastError(23); //Set error to 23
    DWORD error1 = GetLastError(); //store error

    int* test = new int; //allocate int

    DWORD error2 = GetLastError(); //store second error code

    std::cout << error1 << std::endl; //output errors
    std::cout << error2 << std::endl;

    delete test; //free allocated memory
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

If you run it in debug mode, it will give you, because it calls FlsGetValue:

```
23
0
```

However, if you run it in release mode, it produces, because it calls HeapAlloc:

```
23
23
```

Comment: You are misinterpreting the documentation for [HeapAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc). When it says *"If the function fails, it does not call SetLastError."* it simply means that calling `GetLastError` on failure will return an indeterminate value. It does not imply, that the API call will preserve the calling thread's last error.

Answer (score 4):

Per the documentation for [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The Return Value section of the documentation for each function that sets the last-error code notes the conditions under which the function sets the last-error code. Most functions that set the thread's last-error code set it when they fail. **However, some functions also set the last-error code when they succeed.** If the function is not documented to set the last-error code, the value returned by this function is simply the most recent last-error code to have been set; **some functions set the last-error code to 0 on success and others do not.**

At some point during the construction of `std::string`, `SetLastError` is called. The standard library on windows uses Win32 calls as part of its implementation.

Your second method (that works) is the correct way to use `GetLastError`

> You should call the GetLastError function immediately when a function's return value indicates that such a call will return useful data. That is because some functions call SetLastError with a zero when they succeed, wiping out the error code set by the most recently failed function.

Comment: Yea I can guess that much. But nowhere in the documentation of std::string that I'm aware of does it note the conditions of setting the last-error code, so it really shouldn't, according to the documentation you've quoted. Also, allocating memory will likely go through HeapAlloc which is explicitly stating that is does _not_ call SetLastError.

Comment: @Stefan The docs for `HeapAlloc` don't say that. All that you can draw is "An application cannot call `GetLastError` for extended error information."

Comment: @Stefan I agree, the documentation surrounding what sets `GetLastError` is not very good. The documentation does take that into account though (the second quote). You shouldn't rely on it being documented, and should always call `GetLastError` immediately when needed, as anything can set it.

Comment: @Stefan: *"But nowhere in the documentation of std::string that I'm aware of does it note the conditions of setting the last-error code"* - It doesn't, because the C++ Standard Library never documents implementation details. And it needn't either, because the documentation for [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) is **crystal clear** as is: *"You should call the GetLastError function **immediately** when a function's return value indicates that such a call will return useful data."*

Answer (score 0):

This is normal - the "last error" can be set indirectly through any function call.
Some functions set it to "no error" on success, so if you want to use it reliably you need to store it immediately before you do anything else.

If you've ever encountered an "A serious error occurred: The operation completed successfully" dialogue, this is probably the reason.

Comment: Not any function. Only functions that document this behaviour. See answer from Ics.

Comment: Documentation is frequently wrong with regard error code. Just because a function doesn't document that it sets it, is no guarantee that it won't anyway.

Comment: MS says "If the function is not documented to set the last-error code, the value returned by this function is simply the most recent last-error code to have been set", which implies (at least to me) that it can be set indirectly by another function.